# Proof that $0$ is not in the codomain of the following complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the functions

> $f:[0,1]\times\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $f(x,y)=(1-x)y+xy/|y|$,
>   $g:[0,1]\times\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $f(x,y)=(1-x)\bar{y}+x/y$.

How do I prove that $0$ is not reached by these functions, and thus that the ranges of $f$ and $g$ are $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$?

Comment: I think you mean *range*, not *codomain*.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: The standard technique is to assume that $f(x,y) = 0$ for some $(x,y)$, and manipulate the resulting equation to arrive at a contradiction. For instance, $f(x,y) = 0 \iff (1-x)y|y| = -xy$. Now, either $x \in \{0,1\}$, which implies $y = 0$, which is not in the domain, or $x\in (0,1)$, which implies that $|y| = -x/(1-x) <0$, which is impossible.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks, if you make an answer out of that and add the method for $g$, I can accept it. :)